# checking for at least 1 number between 0-9 in a given password using c#

Tags: c#, for-loop, passwords, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to cycle through each char in a string to see if any of them are a number between 0-9. I'm getting an index out of bounds error for the numCheck array, so I know that my issue is that when I attempt to run, the IDE expects the length of txt_Pass.Text to = the number of chars I have in my array. This is wrong, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Would I need to use a vector since I'm not sure how long the input password will be? Or am I totally off?

```
        char[] numCheck = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' };

        for (int i = 0; i < txt_Pass.Text.Length; i++)
        {
            if (txt_Pass.Text[i] != numCheck[i])
            {
                lbl_Form1_NumError.Visible = true;
            }
            lbl_Form1_NumError.Visible = false;
        }
```

'''

Comment: you need to run another loop for comparing each char with num

Comment: you loop is checking if your `txt_Pass.Text` is starting with `0123456789`

Comment: You could be really annoying, `"^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{8,}$"` regex to test minimum eight characters, at least one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter and one number:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *will* get an array index problem for any string with more than ten characters, since you iterate over all those values ***and use that iteration index to look into the `numCheck` array as well.*** Since this only has ten elements, accessing the 11th is a no-no.

A naive approach would be to have two *nested* loops to check if any character in `numCheck` is equal to any character of the input string, something like (this could be optimised somewhat but I haven't bothered since, as you'll find out below, it's totally unnecessary)

```
bool hasADigit = false;
for (int i = 0; i < txt_Pass.Text.Length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < numCheck.Length; j++) {
        if (txt_Pass.Text[i] == numCheck[j]) {
            hasADigit = true;
        }
    }
}
// hasADigit is true if it, well, has a digit :-)
```

But, as stated, this isn't really necessary when C# provides all sorts of wondrous library functions to do the heavy lifting for you:

```
bool hasADigit = (txt_Pass.Text.indexOfAny(numCheck) != -1);
```

In summary, your entire code block can be reduced to:

```
char[] numCheck = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
lbl_Form1_NumError.Visible = (txt_Pass.Text.indexOfAny(numCheck) == -1);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest solution combines LINQ's [Any](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.8) and [`Char.IsDigit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.isdigit?view=netframework-4.8):

```
lbl_Form1_NumError.Visible = !txt_Pass.Text.Any(char.IsDigit);
```

Answer (score 0):

LINQ to the rescue!

```
var numCheck = new char[] { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' };
lbl_Form1_NumError.Visible = txt_Pass.Text.Any(c => numCheck.Contains(c));
```

Regex to the rescue!

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

lbl_Form1_NumError.Visible = Regex.IsMatch(txt_Pass.Text, @"\d")
```